# WCF issue while deploying on IIS 7

Tags: wcf, web-services, .net-3.5

We are hosting WCF services and using .Net 3.5 framework. Everything was working ok on Visual Studio server. But trying to deploy on IIS 7, we get the following error:

The CLR type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory, System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35', provided as the Factory attribute of the ServiceHost directive in the '.svc' file, does not derive from ServiceHostFactoryBase.

Has anyone faced such issue?

Comment: Your IIS setup is referencing the wrong runtime version. 3.5 runs on the 2.0 CLR.

Comment: I need to change the Application Pool to refer to .Net Framework v2.0 in IIS?

Comment: First port of call, yep.